# Hilbert space of toric code on a lattice

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, lattice-model

Kitaev mentions that if one places a $k\times k$ square lattice on a torus, and place a qubit on each edge of the lattice then there are $n=2k^2$ total qubits.

Why is this so? Shouldn't there only be $n=k^2$ total qubits, a single qubit on each edge?

Comment: Try drawing a diagram for, say, $k=3$. You can draw it in the plane formed by unwrapping the torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ refers to the number of vertices. Each vertex is connected to $4$ edges, which would mean $4k^2$ qubits, but each edge is shared by $2$ vertices, so that number must be halved to give $2k^2$.